# HttpAsyncClient can not send many requests per second to a specific ROUTE(host)

Tags: java, apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpasyncclient

why Apache HttpAsyncClient just send 10 request per second. Am i config something wrong? it my way to start an asyncClient:

```
PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager connManager = null;
    try {
        if (client != null && client.isRunning()) {
            client.close();
        }

        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (certificate, authType) -> true;
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
                .loadTrustMaterial(null, acceptingTrustStrategy).build();
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,
                SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry =
                RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory> create().register("https", sslsf).build();

        Registry<SchemeIOSessionStrategy> socketRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<SchemeIOSessionStrategy>create()
                .register("http", NoopIOSessionStrategy.INSTANCE)
                .register("https", new SSLIOSessionStrategy(sslContext, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER))
                .build();

        connManager = new PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager(
                new DefaultConnectingIOReactor( IOReactorConfig.custom()
                        .setConnectTimeout( connectionTimeout * 1000 ) //connectTimeout
                        .setSoTimeout( readTimeout * 1000 ) //readTimeout
                        .setIoThreadCount(10000)
                        .build() ), socketRegistry );
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    client = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
            .setMaxConnPerRoute( maxConnsPerRoute )
            .setConnectionManager( connManager )
            .setMaxConnTotal( maxConnections )
            .setKeepAliveStrategy( DefaultConnectionKeepAliveStrategy.INSTANCE )
            .build();

    client.start();
```

and, it's my way to use it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
     client.execute(request.getHttpPost(), null);
}
```

How can I achieve more request per second???

Answer (score 2):

All versions of Apache HttpClient can easily generate tens thousand of requests per second.

https://github.com/ok2c/httpclient-benchmark/wiki

The performance issue likely lies either with the server code or with your application code.

1. Do not do this. This is awful. One should not be using more I/O dispatch threads than there are CPU cores on the system. Do not override the default value unless you have a very strong reason to do so.

   ```
   .setIoThreadCount(10000) // do not do this
   ```
2. If one manually sets a connection manager all connection management parameters have no effect. Both `maxConnsPerRoute` and `maxConnections` values in your code have no effect. You need to apply them directly to the connection manager.

   ```
   .setConnectionManager( connManager ) // if you do this
   .setMaxConnPerRoute( maxConnsPerRoute ) // this has no effect
   .setMaxConnTotal( maxConnections )
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your response. just one question: in topic 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34505271/how-does-httpasyncclient-4-work', they said that: By default HttpAsyncClient permits only two concurrent connections to the same host per RFC 2616 specification.

Is it correct? because i send all request to the same host.

Comment: That is correct. HttpAsyncClient 4.1.x uses only two concurrent connections by default. If you like to increase that number you can do it through `ConnPoolControl` interface implemented by the connection manager.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. base on your suggestion, i can send more request per specific route and it's solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of thanks to [Okta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335638/ok2c), based on his guidance, I add this codes to my project, and the problem solved:

```
connManager.setMaxTotal(10);
connManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(10);
HttpHost host = new HttpHost("75.10.91.11", 8443, "https");
connManager.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(host), 10);
```

You can find fully explanation in [baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-connection-management)